# Schedule a notification depending on the data in the database when the app is closed - flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, notifications, sqflite

I need to schedule a notification at an exact time, but not to show it except if a certain value exists in the SQLite database.

This can be done in another way, by checking the database daily at 00:00, and scheduling the notification depending on the data.

So, I need to control if the OS should show a notification or not depending on the database, or I need to use the database and schedule the notification when the app is closed.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the notification by checking the flag in the database. For example: if the
Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE notification(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,description TEXT, time TEXT, showNotification TEXT)
```

Map database to a model:

```
Reminder(
          id: map['id'],
          name: map['name'],
          description: map['description'],
          time: map['time'],
          showNotification: map['true'] ? true: false,
);
```

If showNotification flag is true, set the notification or else, do not set notification

Comment: I need to schedule the notification when the app is terminated. The scheduling process itself not the notification.